# "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" whan compressing jQuery with press

Tags: jquery, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to use press module in my Play! application to reduce amount of loaded JS files. I want to merge all loaded JS files into one using press. 
I've wrote following code:

```
    #{press.script src:'jquery-1.7.1.min.js', compress:false/}
    #{press.script src:'x.common.js', compress:false/}
    #{press.script src:'jquery.html5-placeholder-shim.js', compress:false/}
    #{press.script src:'jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js', compress:false/}
    #{press.script src:'jquery.cookie.js', compress:false/}
    #{press.script src:'jquery.autotab-1.1b.js', compress:false/}
    #{press.script src:'jquery.tmpl.min.js', compress:false/}
    #{press.script src:'jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js', compress:false/}
    #{press.script src:'jquery.tools.min.js', compress:false/}
    #{press.script src:'fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js', compress:false/}
    #{press.script src:'log4javascript_lite.js', compress:true/}

    #{press.compressed-script /}
```

But when I try to run it I receive "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" in generated JS on line:

```
(function($) {
```

So I see that jQuery is undefined here. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you had a look in the JS debug console whether there's an earlier error?

Comment: What happens if you set `press.enabled=false` in your `application.conf`? I think one of your JS sources must be faulty ...